# Is it possible to send information to a chat with php?

Tags: php, chat

I have a log-in system, where people can login with an username. I really want to connect a chat to my website. And I have found a place, where I can create a free chat.

```
http://infowish.dk/chat/pjirc/pjirclogon.php?channel=
```

(i know its written in danish)

Is it possible to write some php code, which can make the user get automatic on the chat with her/his username as a chatname, when the user clicks on the link to the chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible with the web chat you linked. It would, however, be possible with Freenode's web chat. You can link the user directly to the chat like this:

```
<?php
$username = 'EdoDodo';
$channel = 'MyChannel';
$url = "http://webchat.freenode.net/?nick=$username&channels=$channel&uio=d4";
echo "<a href='$url'>Go to chat</a>";
```

This chat is built on IRC, so more advanced users with an IRC client can use their choice of client instead of the web chat one.

Answer (score 0):

The chat you want to use is making use of a java applet. I have no clue of the underlying protocol used (e.g. IRC protocol), so I can only answer the question indirectly:

No, it's not possible to interact with a java applet from within PHP programmatically.

You might be looking for some [XMPP based](http://xmpp.org/) chat solution, for which PHP libraries do already exist.